# Cordova | App unresponsive when Android phone comes back from sleep

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap, apache-cordova

I am having this issue and I am not able to narrow down the cause.

My Cordova app UI becomes unresponsive and stops responding to touch events when the phone comes back from sleep ( i.e I let the phone's display turn off while the App was open and come back to it after some time).

**Phone Details:**

- Samsung galaxy S6 (SM-G920I)
- Android v 7.0

**Cordova Details:**

- version 8.0.0
- "android-minSdkVersion" value="15"

**Plugins used:**

- cordova-plugin-whitelist
- cordova-plugin-splashscreen
- cordova-plugin-camera
- cordova-plugin-crop
- cordova-plugin-screen-orientation
- com.lampa.startapp
- cordova-plugin-device
- cordova-plugin-x-toast
- phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner
- cordova-plugin-file

What might be causing this issue?

Comment: Can you add more info like that phone is that, android version, cordova and cordova-android versions? And what plugins have you installed in such app?

Comment: @andreszs I have added the details, please check

Comment: @SapneshNaik Did you ever solve this? I'm running into this same problem now with Android 8.

Comment: @jimmy Alas, I cannot remember. I probably didn't solve it.